# C++ possible to overload `operator<<` to display map?

Tags: c++, dictionary, printing, operator-overloading

I overloaded my `operator<<` as the following:

```
friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, Data& e)
{
    // possible code for printing map..
    return os;
}
```

And I have a `map<string, vector<int>> table`, my question is, is it possible to access and print out the map through `e.table`?

Comment: To answer the question asked: yes, it is possible.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Hi, ok. Do you need to have a `operator<<` overloading for `pair<string, vector<int>>` in order to print this? Because this gives me error `ostream_iterator<pair<string, vector<int>>> oi(cout, " "); copy(e.table.begin(), e.table.end(), oi); `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can. For example.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

std::ostream & operator <<(std::ostream &os, 
                           const std::map<std::string, std::vector<int>> &m)
{
    for (const auto &p : m)
    {
        os << p.first << ": ";
        for (int x : p.second) os << x << ' ';
        os << std::endl;
    }

    return os;
}

int main()
{
    std::map<std::string, std::vector<int>> m =
    {
        { "A", { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 } },
        { "Z", { 5, 4, 3, 2, 1 } }
    };

    std::cout << m << std::endl;
}
```

The program output is

```
A: 1 2 3 4 5
Z: 5 4 3 2 1
```

Or

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

class Data
{
public:
    friend std::ostream & operator <<(std::ostream &os, const Data &d);

private:
    std::map<std::string, std::vector<int>> m =
    {
        { "A",{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 } },
        { "Z",{ 5, 4, 3, 2, 1 } }
    };
};

std::ostream & operator <<(std::ostream &os, const std::map<std::string, std::vector<int>> &m)
{
    for (const auto &p : m)
    {
        os << p.first << ": ";
        for (int x : p.second) os << x << ' ';
        os << std::endl;
    }

    return os;
}

std::ostream & operator <<(std::ostream &os, const Data &d)
{
    return os << d.m;
}

int main()
{
    Data d;
    std::cout << d << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for answering. Your `operator<<`'s second argument is a `map`, mine is `Data& e`. Is it possible to print out through `e.table`?

Comment: Because in my `main()`, it's not declared as a `map<string, vector<int>> m` like you did. It's simply `cout << m << endl;`

Comment: @user3941584 No problem. Just output e.table.

Comment: @user3941584 The operator is defined  for any object of type std::map<std::string, std::vector<int>>.

Comment: Ok will give it a try!

Comment: Hi, I gave it a try. If I comment out my `friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, Data& e)`, then the compiler complains about `operator<<` no match. If I included it, and inside it I have `os << e.table; return os` then there is another no match error.

Comment: @user3941584 You asked how to overload the operator for std::map<std::string, std::vector<int>> I showed you how it can be done. What is the problem?

Comment: Sorry I wasn't so clear with the problem I'm having. In my main I don't declare a `map` like you did, I use `Data d; cout << d << endl;` and trying to print a `map` that is declared inside that class.

Comment: @user3941584 It is unimportant where you declared an object of the map. Just place the operator before the declaration of the object.

Comment: Ok, but I'm still not sure how my `friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, Data& e)` should be? It gives me an error when I try to `os << e.table; return os;` even after implemented `ostream & operator <<(ostream &os, const map<string, vector<int>> &m)`

Comment: Or `ostream_iterator<pair<string, vector<int>>> oi(cout, " "); copy(e.table.begin(), e.table.end(), oi);` also gives an error.

Comment: @user3941584 friend std::ostream & operator <<( std::ostream &os, const Data &e ) {  return os << e.table; }

Comment: Yes, I did try it. It keeps giving me an error about no match for operator<<, even though I added the `operator<<` you provided. It's bugging me out.

Comment: Ok, wow. Can't believe I stuck on this for the whole night. I keep getting the error because I made my `operator<<`'s body inside the class, instead of declaring and implemented it after.